# Other ways to control ARC-1200 RAID status

Tags: windows-10, raid-1

I am having a problem managing the RAID disks we have on our workstation. There's already an `ARC-1200` controller from `ARECA` and we have Win 10 OS. I have installed the `ArcSAP` controller Utility. However, if the program is not turned on it will not send SMTP emails if a message is generated. More importantly, I don't like to have this program running in the foreground of Win 10 all the time, and it seems there's no way to run it in the hidden/background mode.

My question: Is there a way to control this behaviour, or a CLI facility (I know there is but don't know how to batch/DOS it), to make a scheduled task of this thing.

Comment: The support page for this device clearly states that it supports CLI interaction. So, what research have you done? Have you read the documentation for the product before asking here to learn about the commands that are supported?

Comment: @music2myear Thanks this is a good question though I expect just the editors to question the post and take decisions. I think I mentioned that this is supported in my question. After passing almost a day trying to do this and automate the GUI app, I wasn’t able for many reasons. So I asked my question upon the belief that on this site we share our own experience for similar cases. I think if YOU had done a bit of research, then you would have discovered that I’d had some problems with LaTeX editing then I discovered the solution and answered my own question publicly for the common good.

Comment: I meant to delete that first comment earlier today after reading the support page, but it slipped my mind. We can only operate based on the information you have given us. You did not tell us what you have tried doing in the question, so how were we to know. The system supports CLI, so why were you trying to "automate the GUI"? I don't tend to creep on people asking questions here unless their name comes up several times in a short period for interesting reasons. Yours hasn't so I didn't go looking up your profile details.